# P to V conversion inplace with hyper-v possible?

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, hyper-v

I currently have a Server 2008 box (32 bit install running w/o hyper-v installed, but on 64bit hardware).  I'd like to get this machine running Server 08 with hyper-v and grab a snapshot of the current 08 install to run as as VM.

whats the best process to get this converted?  I was thinking of:

1. using vmware tools to p-to-v the box (using VMware vCenter Converter).
2. convert the vmware image to a vhd (using vmdk to vhd convertor).
3. install 64bit server 08 w/ hyper-v on the box
4. attach the vm

does that sound doable?  (It doesn't look like I can use the new MS virtual management tools since those are 64bit only and my one 64 bit box is tied up with a 32bit install. bah.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the built in windows backup tool in 2008 to create a backup image.  That image can then be used during a new guest host install to get the server into the virtual environment.

Comment: nice easy solution!  I did, however, need to do this:

http://www.backupassist.com/blog/support/how-to-restore-a-server-2008-image-backup-to-a-new-hyper-v-vm-from-nas/

Answer (score 2):

See this thread: [How do I convert a VMWare VMDK HDD file to a HyperV VHD file?](https://serverfault.com/questions/26001/how-do-i-convert-a-vmware-vmdk-hdd-file-to-a-hyperv-vhd-file) for issues people have had with converting vmdk's.

Are you sure scvmm 2008 r2 rc requires x64 (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scvmm/bb679924.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, SCVMM requires x64 (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc764213.aspx).  The Administrator Console, Self service portal, and library server can be on a 32-bit server, but the actual VMM server itself requires an x64 OS.

Answer (score 2):

I have migrated my physical Windows 2003 server into a Hyper-V guest using the [backup-restore avenue with Acronis Universal Restore](http://icelava.net/forums/thread/4870.aspx). It may be possible to do the same with Windows 2008 *provided* they have a build of Universal Restore that can rewrite the HAL for Windows 2008 during the restoration process so it can interface with the virtual hardware. You'd have to inquire with Acronis if they already [support Windows 2008](http://www.acronis.com/enterprise/products/ATIES/universal-restore.html).